# IIS 10 hit Invalid hostname while using IP

Tags: iis-10

I am inserting the IIS website by batch with APPCMD. I can the website with localhost and IP without restarting window. After i restart window, the website cannot access with IP but localhost can.

I expecting can access the website with IP

Comment: Before expecting something to work, first check if you have the correct site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check your site's bindings - open iis, select each site, then look to the right and click on bindings. If the binding is set to 127.0.0.1 or ::1 then this will be your problem, you will have to assign it to "all unassigned" or a single IP.

Please check that your web server is configured to listen on your 192.168.** IP address. IIS listens on all IP addresses by default, enter the following command to display the list of IP addresses to listen on: netsh http show iplisten. If no IP address is shown, IIS will listen on all IP addresses by default. If the list is not empty, one or more IP addresses are configured in the list and you need to add a new IP address, for example: netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=192.168.**. It might also work if you just remove all IP addresses from that list...

Please check whether Windows Firewall or any third-party firewall software is blocking requests on the specific ports used by your website. If so, you must create a firewall inbound rule to allow traffic on the port your website is running on.